# Use Spring xd with gemfire-json-server to connect Apache geode. Json can't be parsed

Tags: spring

The stream:

```
stream create --name stocks --definition "http --port=9000 | gemfire-json-server --host=localhost --port=10334 --useLocator=true --regionName=Stocks --keyExpression=payload.getField('symbol')" --deploy
```

Then Post Data:

```
http post --target http://localhost:9000 --data {"symbol":"FAKE","price":73}
```

then it fail:

> 2016-12-14T09:51:20+0800 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR pool-15-thread-4
>   http.NettyHttpInboundChannelAdapter - Error sending message
>   org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException:
>   Failed to transform Message; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested
>   exception is com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.JSONFormatterException: Could
>   not parse JSON document: [Source: {"symbol":"FAKE","price":73}; line:
>   1, column: 29]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:95)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na] ......
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException:
>   nested exception is com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.JSONFormatterException:
>   Could not parse JSON document: [Source: {"symbol":"FAKE","price":73};
>   line: 1, column: 29]  at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:96)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:90)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]   ... 51 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.JSONFormatterException:
>   Could not parse JSON document: [Source: {"symbol":"FAKE","price":73};
>   line: 1, column: 29]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.JSONFormatter.fromJSON(JSONFormatter.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.springframework.integration.x.gemfire.JsonStringToObjectTransformer.toObject(JsonStringToObjectTransformer.java:37)
>   ~[na:na]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]
>
> ......
>
> Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ServerOperationException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.geode.pdx.PdxInitializationException   at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.handleException(OpExecutorImpl.java:686)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.handleException(OpExecutorImpl.java:613)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.execute(OpExecutorImpl.java:171)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.execute(OpExecutorImpl.java:115)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.PoolImpl.execute(PoolImpl.java:696)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.GetPDXIdForTypeOp.execute(GetPDXIdForTypeOp.java:34)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.ClientTypeRegistration.defineType(ClientTypeRegistration.java:56)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.TypeRegistry.defineType(TypeRegistry.java:179)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.TypeRegistry.defineLocalType(TypeRegistry.java:224)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxWriterImpl.completeByteStreamGeneration(PdxWriterImpl.java:477)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceFactoryImpl.create(PdxInstanceFactoryImpl.java:53)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.json.PdxInstanceHelper.endObjectField(PdxInstanceHelper.java:175)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.JSONFormatter.getPdxInstance(JSONFormatter.java:152)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.JSONFormatter.fromJSON(JSONFormatter.java:56)
>   ~[na:na]  ... 69 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.geode.pdx.PdxInitializationException   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]
>
> ....

springxd Stream created successfully. I think whether i miss some libs? the reason it show the fail : Noclassfound. But i just download the package from the website and change nothing. so I don't know why. May someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Procrastinatus Maximus .
Hi everyone I find the problem was caused by the Geode version. The newest
package change the class path from "gemfire" to "geode". 
so the problem comes.
what you should do is use the previous version:
I use the v1.0.0-incubating.M2.
Problem solved!